# GO - GOOGLE MAPS API - Determine whether a given point is inside or near a polygon or polyline

Tags: go, geometry

My API is about determine whether a given point is inside or near a polygon or polyline. I know there is a solution with Javascript but I don't know how to do that with Go Lang.

Comment: Note that a point cannot be inside a polyline.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no preprocessing is allowed, you check insideness by considering an horizontal line through the point. It crosses the polygon outline when an edge has endpoints on either sides of that line. Then you can check if the intersection of the edge and the line lies to the right of the point. The number of right intersections tells you the insideness (odd means inside).

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/590830/1020730

The distance computation is a little more complex. Consider every line segment in turn, let PQ. Apply a translation that brings P to the origin, followed by a rotation that brings Q to (D, 0). Now, let R the transformed target point. If 0≤Rx≤D, then the distance to the segment is |Ry|. Otherwise, consider it infinite. Then, the distance to a polyline is the shortest among the distances to all segments and the distance to all vertices.

[image]

Comment: Wow, let's remember what did I learn in high school. Thanks so much.

Comment: I found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/

Comment: @ThiệnLý: the translation/rotation work is easy to do in complex numbers, it is a simple linear transformation Z = a z + b.